# How to use @Disposes with String Object in CDI

Tags: java, cdi

I created Producer for @RequestParameter as the following code:

```
@Produces
@RequestParameter
public String getStringParameter(InjectionPoint injectionPoint){
    String name = injectionPoint.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(RequestParameter.class).value();

    if("".equals(name)){
        name = injectionPoint.getMember().getName();
    }

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if(facesContext == null){
        return "";
    }

    return facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(name);
}   

Usage:

@ConversationScope
class bean{
   @Inject
   @RequestParameter("ParamX")
   private String paramX;
}
```

I want that after request is processed , variable paramX will become null. But I can't use @Disposes as the following code, the exception will occur when I deploy ear file in Glassfish.

```
public void close(@Disposes String value) { 
   value=null;
}
```

How should I do for this situation? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2):

> A disposer method allows the application to perform customized cleanup of an object returned by a producer method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Disposes.html

This may be needed for example for files or database connections where a correct cleanup is needed.

In your case your producer method may be called in your bean with it's own scope. Therefore the String will be destroyed when the bean gets destroyed. You don't have to do it on your own.

Please keep in mind that you can qualify your producer to prevent interferences with other producer methods by defining an annotation. Then the producer will only be called when the qualifier annotation is present at the injection point and producer method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbck.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. If you put your String in request scope, it will be dispose automatically disposed at the end of the request. A disposer is here to free resources that won't automatically be freed by the garbage collector (like an open file or listener on messaging queue. It's not a hook for you to destroy the instance: the container will do it.
Here, it's normal that you get an exception, your trying to do the job of the container.